# id=0 Error in assigning new user to a model upon signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, registration

I am trying to allow a current user to invite another user and have that new invitee be assigned to a listing, but am getting an error when the invited user goes to sign up.

There are two models, User and Listing, that are related with a has_and_belongs_to_many on each model.  There is also an Invitation model that contains a token and the listing that the invitee needs to be assigned to.

I am overriding the devise registrations controller:

```
  def new
    resource = build_resource({:invitation_token => params[:invitation_token]})
    resource.email = resource.invitation.recipient_email if resource.invitation
    resource.listings << resource.invitation.listing if resource.invitation
    respond_with resource
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource

    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```

And in my registrations/new view I have:

```
= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :listing_ids
```

When I invite a new user and go to the signup (registrations/new) page, fill out the form, and click submit, I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find Listing with id=0
```

And the following output to the server logs:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-26 14:02:51 -0400
  Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"KdWS08JnnbN61JwKkUsIBNDFvJZnX6E8iN3QOS9149U=", "user"=>{"invitation_token"=>"80c98940448829e7edc623f9886e6930434e245c", "listing_ids"=>"[1]", "first_name"=>"John", "last_name"=>"Williams", "email"=>"johnpkelleher@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
  Invitation Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "invitations".* FROM "invitations" WHERE "invitations"."token" = '80c98940448829e7edc623f9886e6930434e245c' LIMIT 1
  Listing Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 170ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Listing with id=0):
  app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

Why am I getting this error when the listing assigned has an id of 1.